# Tracing this algorithm, is my trace right?

Tags: algorithm, debugging

For a classwork problem I am doing, I am supposed to trace (check for bugs) the following algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
num <- 2
count <- 1
while count < 5
{
    count <- count * num

    if count / 2 < 2
        print "Hello"
    else
    while count < 7
    {
        count <- count + 1
    }

    print "The count is " + count + "."
}
```

When i traced this code, I got

```
num  count  output
2    1      Hello The count is 1.
```

My question is, was my trace right? It looks like there is something else I have to add.

Comment: You should not be seeing `The count is 1`.  If there are any other questions, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: `Hello The count is 2.The count is 7.` that should be the output.

Comment: You can use a debugger tool, it's easier.

Comment: Why do you think that `if count /2 < 2` changes the value of count? Also in your edit you wrote `"num"` instead of `"count"`.

Comment: Why you use `java` tag although your code is just pseudo-code?

Comment: @ikh because it's an intro to java programming class, it's an example to help us get ready to use actual code

Comment: @mjb006 Although you want to make final code into java, your question is not directly related to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are tracing the problem, you need to note down all value changes in the program.

In your program, we have 2 variables to trace: `count` and `num`. From the program, we can figure out 2 facts:

- There is no assignment of `num`;
- All output statements are related to `count`.

Therefore, we should focus on tracing the changes on `count`.

Notice that this block:

```
while count < 7
{
    count <- count + 1
}
```

can be replaced with

```
if count < 7
{
    count = 7
}
```

The workflow of the program can be depicted in English like below:

1. Check if `count` is smaller than 5, `YES` go to 2, `NO` program ends;
2. Double `count`;
3. If `count / 2` is smaller than 2, `YES` go to 4, `NO` go to 5;
4. Print "`Hello`", go to 6;
5. If `count` is smaller than 7, set `count` to 7;
6. Print "The count is `+`count`+`.`", go to 1;

Now the task is to use `1` as initial value of `count` and walk through the work flow until the program terminates.

Let's do it together:

1. `count` equals to 1, so go to 2;
2. Now `count` equals to 2;
3. `count / 2` equals to 1, which is smaller than 2, so go to 4;
4. `Hello` is printed, go to 6;
5. "`The count is 2.`" is printed, go to 1;
6. `count` equals to 2, so go to 2;
7. Now `count` equals to 4;
8. `count / 2` equals to 2, which is **NOT smaller** than 2, so go to 5;
9. `count` is set to `7`;
10. "`The count is 7.`" is printed, go to 1;
11. `count` equals to 7, so program terminates.

Therefore the output will be:

`HelloThe count is 2.The count is 7.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should walk through this.

```
num = 2
count = 1

while 1 < 5
{
   2 = 1 * 2
   if 2 /2 < 2          //since 1 < 2  print Hello
       print "Hello"
   else                //This is skipped because the if was true
      while count < 7
      {
         count <- count + 1
      }
print "The count is " + count + "."      //This prints "The Count is 2
}
```

Then you continue through the while loop with count = 2.

Start of second iteration.

```
while 2 < 5
{
    4 = 2 * 2
```

count changes each time through the loop.